# Kernel error when external display connected. Needs to be reconnected several times

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, display, graphics, display-manager

About 50% of the time when I connect my LG external monitor to my x1c7 laptop, the displays are both on and working, but I can only see my mouse and nothing else.

It flashes every few seconds like it's adjusting the resolution and occasionally a window will appear briefly on one of the displays (in the wrong resolution) and then it will flash black and keep trying. It can get stuck in a loop like this for at least 10 minutes (the longest I've had patience for) and sometimes takes disconnecting and reconnecting the display (sometimes even after multiple tries that doesn't work either and I have to restart).

Also, the display manager in Linux Mint takes suspiciously long to open, and sometimes when I open it, I get the same issue described above (without touching the HDMI cable).

```
Linux x1c7 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.2
Release:    20.2
Codename:   uma
```

/var/log/kern.log

```
Sep  2 11:10:56 x1c7 kernel: [20024.427975] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 50
Sep  2 11:11:29 x1c7 kernel: [20057.799471] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 54
Sep  2 11:11:33 x1c7 kernel: [20062.152448] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 54
Sep  2 11:11:35 x1c7 kernel: [20063.602035] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 50
Sep  2 11:11:42 x1c7 kernel: [20070.809420] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 54
Sep  2 11:11:48 x1c7 kernel: [20076.536745] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 54
Sep  2 11:11:49 x1c7 kernel: [20078.042194] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 50
Sep  2 11:11:51 x1c7 kernel: [20079.487640] [drm:drm_dp_dual_mode_detect [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 54
```